# Matching two Social Media Profiles

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-theory, social-media

How can you check if two profiles from two different Social Media sites are the same? 
What algorithms exist to accomplish this and thereby assigning a weight measure for the match?

Let's say that I have a profile from LinkedIn and another profile from Facebook. I know the properties of these two profiles. What algorithm can I implement to find the matching distance between these two profile.

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 6):

You can try [**machine learning**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) algorithms, specifically classification

For simplicity, let's assume you want a binary answer: yes or not (this can be later improved).

**What you have to do:**

1. Extract the features you have from the two profile and create a
   single instance for two combined profiles. This will be an instance
   needed to be classified
2. Create a training set. A training set is a set of "instances" which you know the classification for (from manually labeling them usually).
3. Run a classification algorithm, given the training set - that will "guess" the classification for the unclassified instances you will later get.

**Some algorithms you might want to use are:**

1. [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) - which is considered by many the best classification algorithm exists today.
2. [Decision Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) - especially [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) - Very intuitive classifier (human readable!) and simple to use, also - very short classification time.
3. [K Nearest Neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) - intuitive and simple to use, but behaves badly when the number of features is big.

   - You can also use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to evaluate how good your results are.
   - For java - there is an open source project called [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) that implement these classification algorithms and more.